# page reloading within layout

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, page-layout

Hello I have a visualforce page integrated into opportunity layout. on button click it should redirect to another page. but the problem is on button click the page is redirecting with in layout but not whole.

[image]

Comment: use target="Blank" with button.

Comment: @Reshma nope, that wont work.

Answer (score 0):

If your button is a javascript button the following should work

```
window.top.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

target="Blank" - this attribute is not available with commandbutton.

You can use a commandLink to redirect to another page and style it as a command button to do the trick like

```
 <apex:commandlink styleClass="btn" target="_blank">
```